# How to create a SQL Command with unknown number of fields?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a SQL Command which executes a simple Select but the table and the fields are received as parameters. The fields are taken from a listView and added to a List to make things easier.You do not know how many items are selected so it must be general, it must apply to any number of fields. Here is my connection and how the function looks..

```
         private List<string> LoadListParam(ListView lv)
         {
             List<string> list=new List<string>();
             foreach (ListViewItem item in lv.Items)
                 list.Add(item.ToString());
            return list;
         }

        private SqlCommand CreateComnd(List<string> param, string table)
         {
             SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;" +
                  "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                 "database=Baza de date proiect; " +
                 "connection timeout=30");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            foreach(string i in param)
             cmd.CommandText = "Select "+..;
        }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `String.Join` to get a comma separated list of fields - `string fields = String.Join(",", param);`

Answer (score 6):

Without foreach:

```
cmd.CommandText = string.Format("Select {0} from {1}",string.Join("," param), table);
```

Comment: +1 makes sure to remmeber about "bobby tables" if `params` comes from user/external source.